# Continuos function- bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, definition, bounded-variation, open-map

Use the definition $\epsilon - \delta$ of continuity for proof that if the function $f: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in a, then $f$ is bounded in an open interval centered on a.

My idea for this exercise is the next.
Let $\epsilon >0$.
We now that $f$ is a continuous function in a, i.e., exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$ |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon. $$
Then for properties of abs value,
$$ |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow -\epsilon+f(a)<f(x)<\epsilon +f(a) $$
$$ |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow f(x)\in ]-\epsilon+f(a),\epsilon +f(a)[ $$
and well, $]-\epsilon+f(a),\epsilon +f(a)[$ is an open interval centered on $f(a)$, but the exercise said me an open interval centered on a, and I don't know what I have to do for the next steps.

Comment: $$|x - a| < \color{red}{0 ~??}$$  I suggest that you proofread/edit your posting.

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice the mistake

Comment: What you did for $f(x)$, you do for $ x$: $a-\delta<x<a+\delta\implies (x-a<\delta \text{ and }a-x<\delta)\implies \max\{x-a,a-x\}=|x-a|<\delta$. It does not work ?

Answer (score 1):

You are (perhaps reasonably) misinterpreting the intended significance of the phrase :

$f$ is bounded in an open interval centered on $a$.

What the statement intends is that there exists an $M > 0$ and a $\delta > 0$ such that

for all $x$, where $a - \delta < x < a + \delta$, you will have that $|f(x)| < M.$

The statement that you are misinterpreting is badly worded, but that is the intent.

The easy approach is to take $\epsilon = 1.$

Then, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ where $a - \delta < x < a + \delta$, by the definition of continuity, you will have that

$$f(a) - 1 < f(x) < f(a) + 1.$$

This justifies the assertion that there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that $f(x)$ is bounded, for all $x$ such that
$a - \delta < x < a + \delta$.